# View with a lot of Components. Multiple Model Objects?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am developing a little MVC app.

The problem: I have a view page which has a form to add events, a form to search for events and a list of events.

It's not a big deal to place the components in single views but I need them in one page. I want a permanent form above the list of events.

The problem is that I don't know what to choice as a model object for the view. If I choice a List of events it's working perfectly with the List but not with the form. If I choice a specific Model Object fitting to the form the list hast problem.

What's the best way to handle such views with forms, lists,... ?

That's my View:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"
Inherits="ViewPage<EventPlaza.Web.Models.EventsListViewModel>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="EventPlaza.Storage.Model" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="EventPlaza.Web.HtmlHelpers" %>

 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
   Home Page
 </asp:Content>



<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<div id="EventControlsContainer">
            <h3><a href="#">Add Event Link</a></h3>
                <div>                    
            <% Html.RenderPartial("AddEvent", new AddEventModel()); %>
            </div>
            <h3><a href="#">Search for Events</a></h3>
                <div>
    <form>
           Place:
        <input id="elementID" name="elementID" type="text" class="inputSearch" />
           Date:
        <input id="datepicker" name="elementID2" type="text" class="inputSearch" />
        <input id="addEvent" type="submit" value="Find Events" />
    </form>
 </div>
        </div>      

   <% foreach(var product in Model.Events) { %>
    <% Html.RenderPartial("EventSummary", product); %>
<% } %>


    <div class="pager">
    <%: Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo,
        x => Url.Action("List", new {page=x})) %>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

This the AddEvent View Control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<EventPlaza.Storage.Model.AddEventModel>"%>

                 <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
<% using (Html.BeginForm("AddEvent", "Event", FormMethod.Post)) { %>
                     Event Link:    
                     <%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EventLink) %>                     
                        Event Name:                            
                     <%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EventName) %><br />
                        Place:                            
                     <%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Place) %>    
                        Starting Date:                            
                     <%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.StartingDate) %>    <br />
                        End Date: 
                     <%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EndDate) %>    
                    <input id="Submit" type="submit" value="Add Event" />
            <% } %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly recommend that you should not be using the Model object from the your Domain Model directly as the type of view instead you should make a custom EventViewModel and keep three different objects corresponding to each partial view you have.

Comment: Do I get this right? You mean an EventViewModel class which basicly has 3 variables for the 3 different needed partial views?

Comment: Yes !. Thats the way you should be modeling everything. In online tutorials they shortcut everything and use the Domain Models direct into the views but thats not a good pattern. You should have a separate class (e.g. EventViewModel) which has exactly the information required in the the view. There should be abstraction between your Domain Model and your View Model.